# How do I get .AllMembers of Hierarchy in olap4j?

Tags: mdx, olap4j

I have an MDX query like this:

```
SELECT {[Gender].[Gender].AllMembers} ON COLUMNS, 
{[Geography].[Country].AllMembers} ON ROWS FROM [myCube]
```

And I am trying to get this query as an olap4j object. I do this to set my dimension:

```
QueryDimension genderDim =  myQuery.getDimension("GENDER");
```

But that produces just one column of "All Genders"  and "All Geographys" respectively.

How do I get them broken down like the MDX query above?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the `MEMBERS` function does that help?

```
SELECT 
  {[Gender].[Gender].MEMBERS}     ON COLUMNS, 
  {[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON ROWS 
FROM [myCube];
```